# Java multi-threaded with CompletableFuture works slower

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

I tried to write code for counting files of certain type on my computer.
I tested both one thread solution and multi-threads asynch solution, and it seems like the one thread is working faster. Is anything wrong with my code? and if not, why isn't it working faster?

The code below:
AsynchFileCounter - The asynchronized version.
ExtensionFilter - The file filter to list only directories and files with the extension specified
BasicFileCounter - The one thread version.

```
public class AsynchFileCounter {
    public int countFiles(String path, String extension) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        ExtensionFilter filter = new ExtensionFilter(extension, true);
        File f = new File(path);
        return countFilesRecursive(f, filter);
    }

    private int countFilesRecursive(File f, ExtensionFilter filter) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> f.listFiles(filter))
            .thenApplyAsync(files -> {
                int count = 0;
                for (File file : files) {
                    if(file.isFile())
                        count++;
                    else
                        try {
                            count += countFilesRecursive(file, filter);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
                return count;
            }).get();
    }

}

public class ExtensionFilter implements FileFilter {
    private String extension;
    private boolean allowDirectories;

    public ExtensionFilter(String extension, boolean allowDirectories) {
        if(extension.startsWith("."))
            extension = extension.substring(1);
        this.extension = extension;
        this.allowDirectories = allowDirectories;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        if(pathname.isFile() && pathname.getName().endsWith("." + extension))
            return true;
        if(allowDirectories) {
            if(pathname.isDirectory())
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class BasicFileCounter {
    public int countFiles(String path, String extension) {
        ExtensionFilter filter = new ExtensionFilter(extension, true);
        File f = new File(path);
        return countFilesRecursive(f, filter);
    }

    private int countFilesRecursive(File f, ExtensionFilter filter) {
        int count = 0;
        File [] ar = f.listFiles(filter);
        for (File file : ar) {
            if(file.isFile())
                count++;
            else
                count += countFilesRecursive(file, filter);
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly your problem is? Providing a code sample is very helpful and I understand you are having issues with different thread speeds, adding extra specific details on your issue will help people answer your question better.

Comment: The BasicFileCounter.countFilesRecursive() does exactly the same work as the 
AsynchFileCounter.countFilesRecursive(). The latter is doing the same job with multiple threads. 
I ran the code on a directory containing thousands of files in hundreds of directories. I thought it would run faster with multiple threads, but for some reason it didn't. I am trying to figure out if there's something wrong with my code, or with my presumption.

Answer (score 1):

You have to spawn multiple asynchronous jobs and must not wait immediately for their completion:

```
public int countFiles(String path, String extension) {
    ExtensionFilter filter = new ExtensionFilter(extension, true);
    File f = new File(path);
    return countFilesRecursive(f, filter).join();
}
private CompletableFuture<Integer> countFilesRecursive(File f, FileFilter filter) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> f.listFiles(filter))
        .thenCompose(files -> {
            if(files == null) return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(0);
            int count = 0;
            CompletableFuture<Integer> fileCount = new CompletableFuture<>(), all=fileCount;
            for (File file : files) {
                if(file.isFile())
                    count++;
                else
                    all = countFilesRecursive(file, filter).thenCombine(all, Integer::sum);
            }
            fileCount.complete(count);
            return all;
        });
}
```

Note that `File.listFiles` may return `null`.

This code will count all files of a directory immediately but launch a new asynchronous job for sub-directories. The results of the sub-directory jobs are combined via `thenCombine`, to sum their results. For simplification, we create another `CompletableFuture`, `fileCount` to represent the locally counted files. `thenCompose` returns a future which will be completed with the result of the future returned by the specified function, so the caller can use `join()` to wait for the final result of the entire operation.

For I/O operations, it may help to use a different thread pool, as the default `ForkJoinPool` is configured to utilize the CPU cores rather the I/O bandwidth:

```
public int countFiles(String path, String extension) {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30);
    ExtensionFilter filter = new ExtensionFilter(extension, true);
    File f = new File(path);
    int count = countFilesRecursive(f, filter, es).join();
    es.shutdown();
    return count;
}
private CompletableFuture<Integer> countFilesRecursive(File f,FileFilter filter,Executor e){
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> f.listFiles(filter), e)
        .thenCompose(files -> {
            if(files == null) return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(0);
            int count = 0;
            CompletableFuture<Integer> fileCount = new CompletableFuture<>(), all=fileCount;
            for (File file : files) {
                if(file.isFile())
                    count++;
                else
                    all = countFilesRecursive(file, filter,e).thenCombine(all,Integer::sum);
            }
            fileCount.complete(count);
            return all;
        });
}
```

There is no best number of threads, this depends on the actual execution environment and would be subject to measuring and tuning. When the application is supposed to run in different environments, this should be a configurable parameter.

---

But consider that you might be using the wrong tool for the job. An alternative are Fork/Join tasks, which support interacting with the thread pool to determine the current saturation, so once all worker threads are busy, it will proceed scanning locally with an ordinary recursion rather than submitting more asynchronous jobs:

```
public int countFiles(String path, String extension) {
    ExtensionFilter filter = new ExtensionFilter(extension, true);
    File f = new File(path);
    return POOL.invoke(new FileCountTask(f, filter));
}

private static final int TARGET_SURPLUS = 3,  TARGET_PARALLELISM = 30;

private static final ForkJoinPool POOL = new ForkJoinPool(TARGET_PARALLELISM);

static final class FileCountTask extends RecursiveTask<Integer> {
    private final File path;
    private final FileFilter filter;
    public FileCountTask(File file, FileFilter ff) {
        this.path = file;
        this.filter = ff;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer compute() {
        return scan(path, filter);
    }

    private static int scan(File directory, FileFilter filter) {
        File[] fileList = directory.listFiles(filter);
        if(fileList == null || fileList.length == 0) return 0;
        List<FileCountTask> recursiveTasks = new ArrayList<>();
        int count = 0;
        for(File file: fileList) {
            if(file.isFile()) count++;
            else {
                if(getSurplusQueuedTaskCount() < TARGET_SURPLUS) {
                    FileCountTask task = new FileCountTask(file, filter);
                    recursiveTasks.add(task);
                    task.fork();
                }
                else count += scan(file, filter);
            }
        }

        for(int ix = recursiveTasks.size() - 1; ix >= 0; ix--) {
            FileCountTask task = recursiveTasks.get(ix);
            if(task.tryUnfork()) task.complete(scan(task.path, task.filter));
        }

        for(FileCountTask task: recursiveTasks) {
            count += task.join();
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. 

I actually wrote code using fork-join and it was slower than the CompletableFuture code. I will try your code, and let you know how it is doing - performance-wise.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. since I am adding up the results in this line:

---

count += countFilesRecursive(file, filter);

---

and using get() to receive the result, I am actually waiting for the result, instead of really parallelising the code.

This is my current code, which actually runs much faster than the one thread code. However, I could not figure out an elegant way of knowing when the parallel method is done.

I would love to hear how should I solve that?

Here's the ugly way I am using:

```
public class AsynchFileCounter {
    private LongAdder count; 

    public int countFiles(String path, String extension) {
        count = new LongAdder();
        ExtensionFilter filter = new ExtensionFilter(extension, true);
        File f = new File(path);
        countFilesRecursive(f, filter);
        // ******** The way I check whether The function is done **************** //
        int prev = 0;
        int cur = 0;
        do {
            prev = cur;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            cur = (int)count.sum();
        } while(cur>prev);
        // ******************************************************************** //
        return count.intValue();
    }

    private void countFilesRecursive(File f, ExtensionFilter filter) {
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> f.listFiles(filter))
            .thenAcceptAsync(files -> {
                for (File file : files) {
                    if(file.isFile())
                        count.increment();
                    else
                        countFilesRecursive(file, filter);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you serious about this “check whether the function is done”?

Comment: This is my first stab at using CompletableFuture. So I know it's a noob question, but yes I'm serious.

Comment: Assuming that the absence of a new value after an arbitrary time span, like 50 ms, is a proof for the completion of the job is so wrong, that you should not even think about it. Especially considering what your operation does **1**) you are not counting directories, so having no new number while traversing nested directories is expected

Comment: **2**) [`LongAdder.sum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html#sum--): “*The returned value is NOT an atomic snapshot; invocation in the absence of concurrent updates returns an accurate result, but concurrent updates that occur while the sum is being calculated might not be incorporated.*” In other words, when the job is still running, you are not guaranteed to see its updates, so you are required to do it the other way round, first, proof that the job has completed, then you can rely on the result of the `LongAdder`.

Comment: I was saying that what I do is wrong. 
I asked what is the right way?

Comment: Your original approach utilizing the future to get the result was correct. You just have to create more futures. Then, the missing piece is how to combine them without waiting. There are multiple solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes to the code:

1. I use AtomicInteger to count the files instead of the LongAdder.
2. After reading Holger's answer, I decided to count directories being processed. When the number goes down to zero, the work is done. So I added a lock and a condition to let the main thread know when the work is done.

   3. I added a check whether the file.listFiles() returns a null. I ran the code on windows and it never did (I had an empty directory, and it returned an empty array), but since it is using native code, it might return null on other OS.

```
public class AsynchFileCounter {
    private AtomicInteger count;
    private AtomicInteger countDirectories;
    private ReentrantLock lock;
    private Condition noMoreDirectories;

    public int countFiles(String path, String extension) {
        count = new AtomicInteger();
        countDirectories = new AtomicInteger();
        lock = new ReentrantLock();
        noMoreDirectories = lock.newCondition();
        ExtensionFilter filter = new ExtensionFilter(extension, true);
        File f = new File(path);
        countFilesRecursive(f, filter);
        lock.lock();
        try {
            noMoreDirectories.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
        return count.intValue();
    }

    private void countFilesRecursive(File f, ExtensionFilter filter) {
        countDirectories.getAndIncrement();
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> f.listFiles(filter))
            .thenAcceptAsync(files -> countFiles(filter, files));
    }

    private void countFiles(ExtensionFilter filter, File[] files) {
        if(files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                if(file.isFile())
                    count.incrementAndGet();
                else 
                    countFilesRecursive(file, filter);
            }
        }
        int currentCount = countDirectories.decrementAndGet();
        if(currentCount == 0) {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                noMoreDirectories.signal();
            }
            finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```